# $GL(n,C)$ as a Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I understand that $SO(3)$, $SU(3)$ are Lie groups since they are associated with rotations (The S excludes reflection). Why is $GL(n,C)$ also a Lie group?

Comment: Even if you didn’t exclude reflections you’d still have a Lie group. Are you familiar with the definitions and looking for a proof, or are you looking more for intuition?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan  I am not familiar with the definitions of lie group, sorry. I was mistaken.

Comment: Then start by reading the definition.